# $p$ and $q$ are both primes where $p \equiv 1$ (mod 4) and $q = 2p + 1$. If $2^p \equiv -1$ (mod q), show that 2 is a primitive root modulo $p$.

Tags: number-theory

I understand how to show that $2$ is a primitive root of $q$, but I am not sure how to use this fact to show that it is a primitive root of $p$ (or whether I should at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're statement is false. Let $p=41, q=83$. Note that $$2^{41} \equiv \left( \frac{2}{83} \right) \equiv -1 \pmod {83}$$
By [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) and [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion). But, $$2^{20} \equiv \left( \frac{2}{41}\right) \equiv 1 \pmod {41}$$
Thus $2$ is not a primitive root of $41$. You're wrong.

Comment: I am asking how to show that 2 is a primitive root of **p**, not q.

Comment: @alisa Then your statement is false.

Comment: Thank you. Must be an error in my book.

Comment: @aik Glad to be of assistance. I see you have changed you're profile name. Could you accept this answer?

Comment: @aik, Did you see my earlier comment?

Answer (score 0):

,By Fermat's Little Theorem $2^{q-1}\equiv1\,$mod $q$. The least number $m$ for which $2^m$ is 1 mod $q$ has to divide $q-1$.   As $q-1$ has only $1,2,p,q-1$  as factors the statement follows.